# select query with AND condition does not work.'"+value_spinner+"' and '"+date_value+"' are both strings

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here is the complete method.After this i used the second method GetSQLiteDatabaseRecords(); for displaying the result in edittext.
+value_spinner+ and +date_value+ are strings that stores value from spinner and button respectively.

```
    GetSQliteQuery = "SELECT * FROM attendance where name ='"+value_spiner+"'AND date='"+date_value+"'";
 _db = openOrCreateDatabase("employee.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        cursor = _db.rawQuery(GetSQliteQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null&& cursor.moveToFirst()){
            // cursor.moveToFirst();
            GetSQLiteDatabaseRecords();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Lunch_timeout.this, "No match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
private void GetSQLiteDatabaseRecords()
{
    in_time.setText(cursor.getString(3).toString());
}
```

i used this way too but still.
`

```
cursor=_db.query(true, mydb.TABLE_Attendance, new String[] {
                        mydb.ATT_COL_4,},
               mydb.ATT_COL_2 + "=?" + " and "  +
                        mydb.ATT_COL_3 + "=?",
                new String[] {value_spiner,date_value},
                null, null, null , null);

            if ( cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    GetSQLiteDatabaseRecords();
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Lunch_timeout.this, "No match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`
```

Comment: it works fine when i use only one clause but when i use two clause with AND condition it does not give any result.

Comment: space is missing before **AND**

Comment: Can you post what the value of GetSQliteQuery is after the assignment.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on "does not work".

Comment: why dont you use a second parameter for `rawQuery()` method?

Comment: @Techierj after geting result from query i'm displaying it in a Edittext.When i use a single clause it shows the results but when i used both clauses it niether shows the result nor gives the error.

Comment: @pskink i feel this one easy.Can you give me syntax of that method according to my string and coloums.

Comment: there might be possible that there is no entry with the date given by you...

Comment: syntax of what? you are using `rawQuery` with null `selectionArgs` parameter, just pass your arguments here

Comment: @pskink i have checkd the database it shows the entry.

Comment: did you use non null `selectionArgs` inside `rawQuery`? the docs say: `"selectionArgs String: You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings."`

Comment: i have used this method too but still same issue.

Comment: so what is your code using `selectionArgs`? post what you are passing to `_db.rawQuery()` method

Comment: @pskink i have updated the question.

Comment: tried `"SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE name = ? AND date = ?"` ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this -

```
GetSQliteQuery = "SELECT * FROM attendance where name ='"+value_spiner+"' AND date='"+date_value+"'";
```

Comment: Still same problem.Shows nothing